# How to disable USB autosuspend in Manjaro Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, usb

How can I disable [USB autosuspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_saving#USB_Autosuspend) in Manjaro Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer! In the file **/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf** set:

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```